# Proof that every vector space has a basis

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am currently strdying the application of the axiom of choice in different fields of mathematics. The primitive application in algebara is the proof of the following theorem.

```
Every vector space has a basis.
```

> Let $V$ be a vector space which contains the zero vector $\bf{0}$ as it is a property of a vector space. If the only element in $V$ is $\bf{0}$ then empty set $\emptyset$ is the basis.Now suppose that $V$ contains at least one non zero vector and let t $A$ be the collection of all linearly independent subsets of $V$, partially ordered under inclusion $\subseteq$. ($A,\subseteq)$ is a non empty poset as $V$ contains at least one non zero vector meaning $V$ will contain a linear independent set as singleton sets are linearly independent. Now let $C=\{B_k\}_{k\in L}$ be a chain in $A$ and $U=\cup_{B_k\in C}B_k$. To show that $U$ is the upper bound of chain C we need to show that $U$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$.Assume for a contradiction that $U$ is linearly dependent. Then there exists $I$ where $\sum_{\forall i \in I} \alpha_i\bf{v}_i$ $=0$ where $a_i \neq0$ and $\bf{v}_i \neq$ $=0$ such that for each $i k_i \in L$ and $\bf{v}$$_i\in B_k$. Since, $\{B_k\}_{k\in L}$ is a chain there is some $m \in L$ where for all $i \in I, \bf{v}$$_i \in B_m$ implying a contradiction as this suggests that $B_m$ is linearly dependent. Now as $U$ linearly independent it is a subset of L, i.e. $U \subseteq  L$.

> By Zorn's lemma $L$ has a maximal element $M$ where $M$ is a linearly independent set of vectors of $V$. Suppose that $M$ is not a basis of $V$ implying that there is a vector $\bf{u}$ $\in V$ which can not be expressed through a linear combination of vectors in $M$. Then $M \cup \{\bf{u}\}$ is a linearly independent set implying that $M \cup \{\bf{u}\}$ $\subseteq A$ which is a contradiction on the maximality of $M$ as $M \subseteq M \cup \{\bf{u}\}$. Thus, $M$ is a basis of $V$.

I would greatly appreciate any comments on any mistakes or inconsistencies with my proof and also any comments whether any undergraduate level mathematicians with background in the particular subject can make sense of it.

Comment: this was a good question, thanks for asking it, will closely follow this one.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.